# Use plotly offline to generate graphs as images

Tags: python, html, image, python-2.7, plotly

I am working with plotly offline and am able to generate an html file using

```
plotly.offline.plot({"data": data, "layout": layout})
```

It works great. The graph is generated correctly and the html file gets saved to my current directory.

What I want, though is, using plotly offline, is to have an image (.png, .jpg, etc.) file saved instead. Am I on the right track? What do I need to do from here?

Comment: I would fall back to Matplotlib (just mentioning it in case you didn't know the lib)

Comment: I use the ```filename='file', image='jpeg'``` arguments for the plot function, then have the script open the html file and copy the downloaded jpeg from my downloads folder to the directory of the html file. Frankly it's a horrific method, but it does work...

Comment: @JohnCH, thanks for the comment, but I couldn't clearly understand which folder the image file saved.

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
import plotly.offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go

plotly.offline.plot({"data": [go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[4, 3, 2, 1])],
                     "layout": go.Layout(title="hello world")},
                     image='jpeg', image_filename='test')
```

and open it in Chrome

Comment: While it sucks to have to open the browser, from a lot of reading around SO and the plotly forums, this *is* the only/best way to do this with offline at the moment.

Comment: Would you consider making this fully reproducible? **Edit**: deleted my suggestions/request and just did it for you. Feel free to change anything you want. Just thought it would let people try without being confused about potential import/naming errors.

Comment: @LordK, where the image file saved?

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution in the documentation here:

https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/

So a minimal example would be:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

N = 1000
random_x = np.random.randn(N)
random_y = np.random.randn(N)

trace = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y,
    mode = 'markers'
)

data = [trace]

py.image.save_as({'data':data}, 'scatter_plot', format='png')
```

Comment: I saw this, too, but it isn't saving the image from the Notebook, but rather from their server.

Comment: Well, apparently you do need a connection to the server, but the graph does not appear afterwards in your plotly account, so it is not public. Could it be ok for you?

Comment: What I was trying to accomplish was to not have to connect to the plotly server at all. This is to support faster chart creation. I wanted a generated chart saved as an image file without opening the chart and without involving the plotly server. I'm currently thinking there is no way to accomplish this. Additionally, I don't want to use their javascript version because this chart code is not going to make it to the browser at all, but rather a chart will be saved in a pdf behind the scenes.

Comment: Ok, I guess there is hope for the future for you, since plotly offline has just been released. Maybe they will let us save offline in the future.

Comment: It is now possible if you add Plotly's orca to your website @Matt. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243446/how-to-save-plotly-offline-graph-in-format-png/40244933). You can make an image without displaying it.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way of using python plotly graphs offline:

1) Write import statements

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly as plotly
import plotly.express as px
```

2) write your plotly graph code e.g.

```
data = px.data.gapminder()

data_canada = data[data.country == 'Canada']
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop',
             hover_data=['lifeExp', 'gdpPercap'], color='lifeExp',
             labels={'pop':'population of Canada'}, height=400)
```

3) name your figure (provide reader-friendly name :) )

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename= output_filename + ".html")
```

4) Well-done! Please add comments, if you like my answer!

Comment: Yes, for saving the file as .png format simply do : plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename= output_filename + ".png")

Comment: Nope that just generate an html file with the name `output_filename.png.html`

Comment: remove `.html` at the end and replace that with `.png`

Comment: @ShantanuDeshmukh and where this file will be saved? Actually i am using plotly.offline.iplot()

Answer (score 0):

one possibility using ipython notebook is to display the graph and then choose the option "Download plot as png" manually.

Comment: Except I don't want it displayed. The program is part of a website that generates the graphs as part of a pdf that gets emailed to a client. Thanks for the response, by the way.

Answer (score -2):

[Here](https://plot.ly/python/offline/#static-image-export) says to use

```
import plotly.plotly as py
# Generate the figure

trace = Bar(x=[1,2,3],y=[4,5,6])
data = [trace]
layout = Layout(title='My Plot')
fig = Figure(data=data,layout=layout)

# Save the figure as a png image:
py.image.save_as(fig, 'my_plot.png')
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? It's not reproducible (you need `plotly.graph_objs`, which you likely imported locally) and it isn't offline as the user requested. Running this yields `PlotlyRequestError: You must be authenticated to generate an image via json.`