# How to save Plotly Offline graph in format png?

Tags: python, plotly

I am using Plotly offline to generate graph in python.

As per the documentation below,

https://plot.ly/python/offline/

Here is my code, which perfectly generates C:/tmp/test_plot.html file.

```
import plotly.offline as offline

offline.init_notebook_mode()

offline.plot({'data': [{'y': [4, 2, 3, 4]}], 
               'layout': {'title': 'Test Plot', 
                          'font': dict(family='Comic Sans MS', size=16)}},
             auto_open=False, filename='C:/tmp/test_plot')
```

How can I save this graph as png instead of html?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`offline.plot` method has `image='png` and `image_filename='image_file_name'`  attributes to save the file as a `png`.

```
offline.plot({'data': [{'y': [4, 2, 3, 4]}], 
              'layout': {'title': 'Test Plot', 
                         'font': dict(family='Comic Sans MS', size=16)}},
             auto_open=True, image = 'png', image_filename='plot_image',
             output_type='file', image_width=800, image_height=600, 
             filename='temp-plot.html', validate=False)
```

See more details inside `offline.py` or online at `plotly`.

However, one caveat is that , since the output image is tied to HTML, it will open in browser and ask for permissions to save the image file. You can turn that off in your browser settings.

[image]

Alternately, 
You may want to look at plotly to matplotlib conversion using `plot_mpl`.
Following example is from `offline.py`

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot_mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    init_notebook_mode()

    fig = plt.figure()
    x = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
    y = [100, 250, 200, 150, 300]
    plt.plot(x, y, "o")

    plot_mpl(fig)
    # If you want to to download an image of the figure as well
    plot_mpl(fig, image='png')
```

Comment: I am getting an error, while putting image in argument. plot_mpl() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image' / plot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image'. Running on version 1.9.6.

Comment: I updated to plotly version 1.12.9, it works as expected. is there a way to configure saving png directly without accessing html?

Comment: I was going to comment that you may want to upgrade, but you already did :-). Based on my research so far, I don't think so, I checked plotly forums as well. You may want to ask there.Best way is to redirect the plot to matplotlib and save. Or use online method.  see here :https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/

Comment: is there a way to choose the download location of the image? Mine will only go to downloads and changes \ and / to _

Comment: This converts matplotlib to plotly, not the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

Quick update: As of plotly.py 3.2.0, it's now possible to programmatically export figures as static images while fully offline.

This was accomplished by integrating the [orca](https://github.com/plotly/orca) project into plotly.py.  Check out the [announcement post](https://medium.com/@plotlygraphs/plotly-py-end-of-summer-updates-5422c98b9058) for some more details.

Comment: Related to this, but not for offline...If you are using Jupyter and want to share processes incorporating this route to static images via Binder sessions, such as MyBinder.org, see [here](https://github.com/plotly/orca/issues/150#issuecomment-483484860).

Comment: This "improvement" requires psutils to be installed, and orca to be installed as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can automate PhantomJS to save a screenshot with exactly the same width and height as the original image would be when it is downloaded by opening the browser.

Here is the code:

```
import plotly.offline as offline
from selenium import webdriver

offline.plot({'data': [{'y': [4, 2, 3, 4]}],
               'layout': {'title': 'Test Plot',
                          'font': dict(size=12)}},
             image='svg', auto_open=False, image_width=1000, image_height=500)

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="phantomjs.exe")
driver.set_window_size(1000, 500)
driver.get('temp-plot.html')
driver.save_screenshot('my_plot.png')

#Use this, if you want a to embed this .png in a HTML file
#bs_img = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import plotly
from html2image import Html2Image
import os

if not os.path.exists("./tmp"):
    os.mkdir("./tmp")

fig = dict(data = your_data, layout=your_layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='./tmp/look.html',auto_open=False)

hti = Html2Image()
hti.output_path = './tmp/'
with open('tmp/look.html') as f:
    hti.screenshot(f.read(), save_as='ooo.png')
```

Comment: I love you. I love you. I love YOU!!!!

Comment: Note: You can use `pip install html2image` to install the package.