# How to access static image when using Plotly python API

Tags: python, plotly

Following the plotly tutorial on [getting static images through the python api](https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/#export-static-image-offline).

When I execute:

```
import plotly as py
py.offline.plot(data,
                show_link=False,
                image_filename='pandas-bar-chart-binned',
                image='png')
```

My browser auto opens and I get both an HTML file in my parent directory and an image of the chart downloads from the browser, which is to be expected from the docs.

But if I execute:

```
import plotly as py
py.offline.plot(data,
                show_link=False,
                image_filename='pandas-bar-chart-binned',
                image='png',
                auto_open=False)
```

The HTML file is generated in my parent directory, but no image is produced. If I store it as a variable, I get a string that represents the location of the HTML file.

Is there a `save_as` function for `offline`, as there is for `image`?

```
import plotly as py
py.plotly.image.save_as(data, filename='pandas-bar-chart-binned.png')
```

[I have found a handful of suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243446/how-to-save-plotly-offline-graph-in-format-png), but they all seem to point back to opening up a browser rather than saving directly through the file system.

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible right now, https://community.plot.ly/t/use-plotly-offline-to-save-chart-as-image-file/408/21