# Save Plotly Offline image in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, plotly

I have some code that I am plotting in Jupyter Notebook, and all I am trying to do is save the image as a PNG so I can use it as a high DPI image in some work I am doing:

```
data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = {"title": "", 
          "xaxis": {"title": "", }, 
          "yaxis": {"title": ""}}

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

I cannot figure out how to save it as a PNG file, and specifically save it as a PNG file in my Jupyter Notebook folder.

I have tried the solution found here:
[How to save Plotly Offline graph in format png?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243446/how-to-save-plotly-offline-graph-in-format-png)

But I am not sure where to put the code, as my plotly plotting code is different. Everything I do ends up in an error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following by providing the `filename` argument to `iplot`

```
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='filename.png')
```

From the [docs](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#initialization-for-offline-plotting)

> Signature: plotly.offline.iplot(figure_or_data, show_link=True, link_text='Export to plot.ly', validate=True, image=None, filename='plot_image', image_width=800, image_height=600, config=None)

Also make sure that the **Trust button** on upper-right of your notebook shows `Trusted`. If it is not, click on `Not Trusted` it to make it.

[image: the "not trusted" vs "trusted" toggle button in upper-right of Jupyter notebook]

Comment: Hey, thank you for responding. I have tried that (and also a direct link to my desktop), and whilst the code runs, no file called 'filename' exists on my computer :S

Comment: Which system are you using? Mac? Windows?

Comment: I am using Mac?

Comment: @ScoutEU: Try specifying the path using `filename='/Users/username/Desktop/filename.png'` where `username` is your username on Mac. May be you are unable to locate the file at the moment

Comment: Hey, that is what I tried. I have directed it towards my desktop (the same place I import the csv file from for the graph, and nothing appears).

Comment: I have used online instead. I believe your answer is right so I will mark it as accepted. There must be something funky going on with my computer. Puzzling.