# Javascript Plotly. How to create a plot but not actually plot it.

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am using plotly javascript to draw some plots. But what I actually need is the url and I don’t really need the ploly to draw it on the web.

Here is an example, [`https://codepen.io/slfan2013/pen/xpWMyW`](https://codepen.io/slfan2013/pen/xpWMyW). What I really need is the `url` and I don’t want the plot show on the website. How to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to actually plot the plot, you can pass the plotting data in Plotly.toImage, like:

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  mode: 'markers'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 10],
  mode: 'lines'
};

var trace3 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [12, 9, 15, 12],
  mode: 'lines+markers'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

var layout = {
  title: 'Line and Scatter Plot'
};

Plotly.toImage({
    data: data,
    layout: layout
  }, {
    height: 600,
    width: 800
  })
  .then(
    function(url) {
      console.log(url) // this is what i really need!! I dont want it to be ploted~!

    }
  );
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
  </div>
  <script>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE -->
  </script>
</body>
```

let me know if it helped !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, you can set the div CSS property `display:none` so that the graph is not shown. Then use `plotly.purge()` to remove the generated graph after the required content is obtained!

So to summarize, the graph is created(but not visible), the url is obtained, then the graph is purged!

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  mode: 'markers'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 10],
  mode: 'lines'
};

var trace3 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [12, 9, 15, 12],
  mode: 'lines+markers'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

var layout = {
  title: 'Line and Scatter Plot'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout).then(
  function(gd) {
    Plotly.toImage(gd, {
        height: 600,
        width: 800
      })
      .then(
        function(url) {
          console.log(url); // this is what i really need!! I dont want it to be ploted~!
          Plotly.purge('myDiv');

        }
      )
  });;
```

```css
#myDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
  </div>
  <script>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE -->
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: @WCMC does this help you?

Comment: Hi @Naren, thanks for your quick help! It is clever. But actually why I don't want to plot it is because I have a lot of `data`s. I am writing a async loop to generate them all and get the url for each run. By using the code, the plotly still "plot" each even the `display` is set `none`. This won't speed up the code (please correct me if I'm wrong). Is there an direct way?

Comment: @WCMC The problem is that the graph needs to be generated then converted to image, so I am not able to achieve what you need, that is why we have the `.then(` part, you might wanna check this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957790/use-plotly-offline-to-generate-graphs-as-images), plotly offline for python can convert to image itseems, don't know about the efficiency of the conversion!